# Uniform Convergence Proof: $\frac{\sin nx}{n\sqrt{x}} \to 0$

Tags: uniform-convergence

Welcome to MSE! I need assistance in demonstrating the uniform convergence of the sequence $\frac{\sin nx}{n\sqrt{x}} \to 0$.
I've attempted to approach the problem by trying a bounding technique, but my attempts have not been successful. Additionally, I've explored the possibility of finding a suitable sequence to show that it doesn't converge to zero, but my efforts in this direction have been unsuccessful as well.

Could someone help me understand where I might be going wrong in my attempts? Perhaps there's a different approach or insight that I'm missing. Your guidance and suggestions would be immensely valuable. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hint: write this as $\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx} \sqrt{x} < \sqrt{x}$. It is of course also bounded above by $\frac{1}{n \sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: In what domain do you want to check uniform convergence? Without this information, the question makes no sense.

Comment: The domain is $\mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, the sequence converges uniformly on any set that is bounded away from $0$.  For example, if $x \in [a,\infty)$ where $a>0$, then uniform convergence holds since

$$\sup_{x \in [a,\infty)}\left|\frac{\sin nx}{n\sqrt{x}} \right|\leqslant \frac{1}{n\sqrt{a}}\underset{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow 0$$

To prove uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb{R}^+$ consider $x \in (0,a]$.  If the sequence failed to converge uniformly then there would exist $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and a sequence $x_n \in (0,a]$ such that for all $n$

$$\left|\frac{\sin nx_n}{n\sqrt{x_n}} \right|\geqslant \epsilon_0$$

The sequence $(x_n)$ may or may not have a limit but it is bounded and $l=\liminf_{n \to \infty}x_n \geqslant 0.$

If $l =0$, then there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $x_{n_k} \to 0$ and for all positive integrers $k$

$$\left|\frac{\sin n_kx_{n_k}}{n_k\sqrt{x_{n_k}}} \right|= \left|\frac{\sin n_kx_{n_k}}{n_kx_{n_k}} \right|\sqrt{x_{n_k}}\geqslant \epsilon_0$$

However, this is impossible because $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is bounded for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sqrt{x_{n_k}} \to 0$ as $ k \to \infty$.

On the other hand, if $l >0$, then $x_n > l/2$ eventually which means that there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geqslant N$ we have both

$$\left|\frac{\sin nx_{n}}{n\sqrt{x_{n}}} \right|\geqslant \epsilon_0,$$

and

$$\tag{*}\left|\frac{\sin nx_{n}}{n\sqrt{x_{n}}} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{n\sqrt{l/2}}$$

which, again, is impossible since the RHS of (*) tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Using a proof by contradiction we have shown that the convergence of the sequence in question is uniform for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: Thanks for your insightful response!

Comment: @mathselite: You're welcome.